# Why I can't run codes in VS code?

Tags: python

My computer has windows 8 and I get this error when I run a code; [Running] python -u "c:\Users\SCS\Desktop\test.py" 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. It's in the VS code.

I entered a function; Print("Hello World!") for just testing and in the "Output", I got this error; My computer has windows 8 and I get this error when I run a code; [Running] python -u "c:\Users\SCS\Desktop\test.py" 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I expected the output but I got this error.

Comment: You don't have python properly installed on your computer: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, follow the steps below:

Find a folder with the installed Python version as its name in X:\Program Files (where X is the drive where Windows is installed; e.g.,C:\Program Files\Python36). If such a folder does not exist, **download and install the latest version of Python** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmZ10.jpg).

Open this folder and copy its path.

Right-click This PC, then go to **Properties => Advanced system settings => Environment variables**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmZ10.jpg)

In the window that appears when a path variable exists, select it, ​and click **Edit**; otherwise, click **New**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOfdi.jpg)

In the next dialogue box, click on New and paste the previously copied path of the folder; then, click OK.

Reference:[Click Here](https://www.educative.io/answers/err-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)